# MAUI: Unable to add an event handler via XAML if the event is internal

Tags: xaml, events, event-handling, maui, internals

I found an unexpected XAML parser behavior. Here is a page from a MAUI project:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MyPage">
  <local:MyView MyEvent="MyView_MyEvent" />
</ContentPage>
```

`local:MyView` is:

```csharp
namespace MauiApp1;

class MyView: View
{
  public event EventHandler MyEvent;
}
```

Pay attention to the event's `public` modifier. This is a fully working project until I change the modifier to `internal`. The page and `MyView` are entities of the same assembly, so the modifier change should have no affect on the app. However, it causes the `LoadFromXaml` method called from `MyPage.InitializeComponent` to throw a `XamlParseException`. With the `internal` modifier, I can still successfully add the event handler via C#, but not via XAML.

I decided to find out if this behavior is inherent in XAML in principle. In fact, this proved not to be the case. For example, WPF doesn't mind adding handlers to internal events via XAML.

Therefore, I would like to know: is this a bug from the MAUI developers or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing the modifier to `Private`, it'll also throw a `XamlParseException`.And this is a known issue [Private EventHandlers throw an exception on XAML-defined custom control](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11467) in Github, you can follow up it.

Furthermore, I notice you have reported a new issue on Github: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12566 and you can follow up it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue you found is really similar, but still a little different. I wanted to post my issue on GitHub, but first I decided to ask for advice here to be sure this is really an issue, not my lack of understanding on the matter.